# OpenCV Python Import Module

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, opencv

I'm having some issues. I've installed OpenCV 2.3 on an ec2 ubuntu instance - and compiled with the necessaries for python integration. I realised that python was behind so upgraded that to 2.6 afterwards.

All should be good. However, running a basic .py script and calling OpenCV in isn't working. Forgive me if this is a basic error, I'm new to OpenCV.

SCRIPT IS:-

```
import cv
cv.SaveImage("foo.jpg", cv.LoadImage("foo.png"))
```

WHEN RUN IT RESPONDS:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 1, in <module>
    import opencv
ImportError: No module named opencv
```

Am I doing something silly here. I've tried looking at this idea that some have harped on about, of moving stuff to different to different dirs - but not found the files the talk of, specifically finding opencv.so and moving it to python dirs.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to rebuild OpenCV against the new Python you've installed.

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing without downloading tars etc. etc. I upgraded via apt-get. Apologies if this is a stupid question.